# Exit Several Threads on Quit Command

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have a thread which adds commands inputted on the command line to a command queue. One of those commands is a command to quit the program.

```
def cli(cmd_queue):
    while True:
        i = input()  
        if i == "q":
            cmd_queue.put(("QUIT",)) 
            return  

cmd_queue = queue.Queue()

cli_thread = threading.Thread(target=cli, args=(cmd_queue,), daemon=True)
cli_thread.start()
```

I could end another thread like this:

```
def some_thread():
    while True:

       while not cmd_queue.empty():
         cmd = cmd_queue.get()
         if cmd == ("QUIT",): return

         do_stuff()

       time.sleep(0.001)
```

But what might I do if I have several threads in my program, and I wish for all of them to break out of `while True` loops?

**UPDATE**

The threads I wish to break out of have different algorithms, for example:

```
def some_thread_1():
    while True:

       while not cmd_queue.empty():
         cmd = cmd_queue.get()
         if cmd == ("QUIT",): return

         do_stuff()

       time.sleep(0.001)

def some_other_thread_2():
    while True:

       while not cmd_queue.empty():
         cmd = cmd_queue.get()
         if cmd == ("QUIT",): return

         do_other_stuff()

       time.sleep(0.001)
```

Comment: You feed one QUIT tuple for each thread into the queue.

Comment: @quamrana So if there are four other threads that are interested in commands, I would feed a given command into the queue 4 times. Is there not a risk with this solution that one thread would see the command twice and another thread miss the same command entirely. What about having four command queues, one for each thread?

Comment: @Baz No, because as a thread gets a quit message, it quits and doesn't pull any more requests from the queue :)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggested, put a sentinel value for each thread to signal it to exit.  Here's an example.  There's no possibility of a thread getting two sentinels because they stop drawing from the queue once they get one.

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
import time

q = Queue()

# Factory function for creating functions with fixed multipliers of input data.
def mult_factory(n):
    def mult(n=n):
        while True:
            data = q.get()
            if data is None: # Sentinel value?
                break
            print(f'{data} * {n} = {data * n}')
        print(f'Quitting mult{n}')
    return mult

# Create 5 threads with different multiplication factors.
threads = [Thread(target=mult_factory(n)) for n in range(5)]

for t in threads:
    t.start()

# Generate some work
for i in range(10):
    q.put(i)

# Add a "done" for each thread.
for t in threads:
    q.put(None)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Output:

```
0 * 1 = 0
1 * 3 = 3
3 * 4 = 12
7 * 4 = 28
8 * 4 = 32
9 * 4 = 36
6 * 3 = 18
5 * 1 = 5
Quitting mult4
Quitting mult3
Quitting mult1
2 * 0 = 0
4 * 2 = 8
Quitting mult0
Quitting mult2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In the case above your solution makes perfect sense. I'm only starting to develop my application so I dont know yet if this will be a problem for me, but I was thinking what if I also had more unrelated threads created elsewhere in my code, created using for example divide_factory and subtract_factory. In this case I would need to know the number of threads in my code to add the correct number of QUITs to the Command Queue. And maybe there are other commands that I wish to broadcast to those threads that are interested in them, besides just QUIT.

Comment: @Baz Use a common list for the threads being created so you know how many threads you have in total.  Also queue items can be any type, so you could have a special class instead of `None` to hold commands vs. work and test for them with `if isinstance(data,Command):` and then query the object for the command.  In this simple case you could use `int` for work and `str` for commands.

Comment: @Baz Also, only a "quit" type command is going to work for a common queue such as used by a thread pool.  With other commands, you would need targeted command queues for each thread, because otherwise the same thread could pick up a command twice.